# Is there a difference between a list and a tuple?

Tags: list, tuples, theory

I see existing questions that relate to specific programming languages. There are implementation differences in specific languages, but is there a theoretical conceptual difference?

**Mutable vs immutable**: In Python, lists are fully mutable while tuples are immutable or persistently immutable so that modifications create new tuples and do not do in place modifications. But this is purely an implementation detail. In other languages tuples are mutable and lists are immutable.

**Heterogeneous vs homogeneous**: Semantically, tuples are usually heterogeneous, while lists are usually homogeneous, but this is more of a convention and there are many exceptions. Dynamically typed languages like Python have heterogeneous lists. Haskell, for example, has support for fully statically typed heterogeneous lists called HList.

**Finite vs Infinite**: Theoretically, a list can be infinite, and some programming languages (Haskell) support infinite lists. A tuple can not be infinite.

**UPDATE**: The only theoretical difference is that a tuple must be finite, while a list can theoretically be infinite. The rest of the differences are pure implementation differences.

Wikipedia says "A tuple is a finite ordered list of elements.".

This makes it clear that a tuple is a list, but a finite list.

Comment: In which language(s) is mutability the other way?

Comment: C++ lists and tuples are both mutable.

Comment: You may want to move this question to http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I agree with the move to cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tuple is just a finite list. All tuples are lists. All finite lists are tuples. Infinite lists are not tuples. All differences of typing and semantics are purely language dependent considerations.

Answer (score 2):

From a C# perspective, the most glaring difference would be that Tuples are fixed length over the duration of their existence, whereas Lists support add and remove functionality that may cause their lengths to change.

You could argue this is just an arbitrary implementation decision, but this leads back to the mutability issue. Say I have a `Tuple<double, double>` to represent a 2D point. If I remove one of the elements so I have `Tuple<double>`, it is clear that this is no longer a 2D point and the original meaning of even the remaining dimension is likely no longer relevant or usable.

If, however, I had a `List<double>` representing 2 students' scores, and remove one, I now have a list of 1 student's score. But the one remaining double is still a score and still retains the full meaning / relevance of a score.

In short, I see Tuple elements as attributes or dimensions (usually the minimally required defining set), whereas I see List elements as arbitrary instances.

Comment: C++ is very similar in this regard. You can concatenate tuples with `tuple_cat`, but that's really just creating a new tuple with a new type.

Comment: The first difference is simple immutability. In C#, like Python or Scala, tuples are immutable by default. You can add/remove elements but that creates a new tuple and keeps the original unchanged. The second distinction is purely semantic. If you had a list of test scores, semantically most would use a list, but you could use a tuple

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, a tuple might be a list of elements and therefore also a list, but I don't know about the specifics of tuple and list in that domain. From a programming point of view I see a semantic difference which is that the list is a container for elements and the tuple is an object that represents multi-dimensional data (2D or 3D points for example). So you would not use a tuple to save a list of elements. Instead you use a tuple to represent multi-dimensional data.

Comment: A 2D/3D point is a list of coordinates. A tuple is always a list of elements.

Comment: I don't agree with the dimension requirement, a tuple has no semantic constraint in the way a Point  might.

Answer (score 1):

A tuple is a subtype of a list with additional type constraints for each of the elements and a defined size as part of its type. If a list has size constraints and specifies the types of all its elements, (like Haskell's HList) then it is also a Tuple conceptually.

Not all lists are tuples, but all tuples are lists.

The relationship between a tuple and a list is the one between negative numbers and numbers. Not all numbers are negative numbers, but all negative numbers are numbers.

Comment: The differences you cite are arbitrary and implementation specific. There are list implementations such as Haskell/Scala HList that have the size and element type encoded in the type system. In mathematics, the only difference is that a tuple must be finite, where lists can be finite or infinite.

Comment: Yup, we are always talking language agnostic here. I fail to see the difference between a Heterogeneous list with fixed size and strict element types; and a Tuple of the same size and type signature.
A Tuple is a subtype of Heterogeneous Lists In the same way that negative numbers are a subset of numbers.
Let me see if I can change the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: All tuples are lists. All finite lists are tuples. Infinite lists are not tuples, because tuples must be finite. The typing/size constraints are purely language dependent considerations.