# Is there a purpose for tuples besides being immutable?

Tags: list, data-structures, tuples

I frequently see the use of tuples, in contrast to lists, which are mutable. As an intermediate programmer in high school, I am still confused as to the usefulness of tuples.

Are there any other reasons to use them besides their immutability (which is the major response I see to this question)? I know lists can be changed, but is that really such a big problem when programming, other than 'accidents' that might change a list you don't want changed?

Another reason I see, like in this post -- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518013/is-there-a-difference-between-a-list-and-a-tuple](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) -- is that you can imagine them different conceptually, such as by imagining them as coordinates, rather than an array of numbers. But this isn't really a function, but a practice that arose because of the freedom for an unchanging structure that tuples supposedly give.

What I'm asking is there a need to have defined a totally new data structure that doesn't really serve a new purpose in my opinion. Thanks! hope this question isn't too dumb :\

Comment: Guarding against "accidents" is actually quite a major feat. Also, mutable types like `list` can't be put into `set` or used as keys for a `dict`.

Comment: Related: [Difference between list and tuple?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9969649/difference-between-list-and-tuple-minus-immutability-in-python?rq=1) and [What's the difference between lists and tuples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-lists-and-tuples)

Comment: I was not aware that lists could not do that, thank you!

Comment: Note also in python there are `set` and `frozenset`. The distinction between the two is more or less the same as the distinction between `list` and `tuple`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Tuples are immutable
2. Tuples can describe things like coordinates and dimensionality better than `list`
3. To guard against accidents
4. Tuples can be put into `set` and used as keys for `dict`